# Confusion over the value of a variable after running a PHP program

Tags: php, variables, post-increment

I'm studying for my finals and I came across this question:

> consider this following PHP code, write the output after executing it
>
> ```
> <?php
>  $a=3;
>  $b=$a++;
>  IF($a>$b)
>  {
>    echo "a>$b";
>  }
>  else if ($a == $b)
>  {
>    echo "a=$b";
>  }
>  else
>  {
>    echo "a < $b";
>  }
>  ?>
> ```

When I output it in my text editor I get `a < 3`, but I don't understand why though?

I thought a is assigned to 3 and also b is assigned to a++ 3 and 3==3 so should a==3 be printed out?

Answer (score 5):

No, you are using post-increment operator on `$a`. So, `$b` will be assigned a value of 3, and later, when the statement is executed, `$a` will increment itself by one, and become 4. So, you'll now be comparing `$a as 4` and `$b as 3`.

Hence you get the result `a > 3`

Answer (score 2):

The `$a++` incrementation happens *after* the expression gets evaluated, while `++$a` would happen *before*.

So in your case, `$b` was first set to 3, and then `$a` was increased.

Answer (score 1):

`$a++` tells the variable `$a` explicitely to increase, no matter if you assigning to another variable or not!
This gives the possibility to do things like `if ($a++ > 10) { // ...` in loops.

For your case you would have to take `$b = $a + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $a=3;
 $b=$a++;
// $b = 3 and $a = 4 now
 IF($a>$b)
 {
   echo "a>$b";
 }
 else if ($a == $b)
 {
   echo "a=$b";
 }
 else
 {
   echo "a < $b";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I get:

```
a>3
```

which makes sense

$a is 3 but is increased to 4 when you do $a++

$b is just $a before the ++ action so it stays 3

Think of `$a++` as `$a = $a + 1` then it makes sense